# After Wi-Fi Scan, show current Wi-Fi list logcat on android

Tags: android

I want

first, current Wi-Fi scan.
second, if Wi-Fi scan finish, check current Wi-Fi list.
third, show current Wi-Fi list on logcat.

my source

```
WifiManager wifi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(WifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE));
    wifi.startScan();

} 

private final BroadcastReceiver WifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
              List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
              for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
               Log.d(TAG, "get current wifi lists ->" + mScanResults.get(i).toString());   
              }
          }
       }
}
```

I want get current wifi list.

but `mScanResults.get(i).toString());`  is null.

why value is null? 
How to get current wifi list?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    WifiManager wifi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }  
     wifi.startScan();
    registerReceiver(WifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)); 

    } 

private final BroadcastReceiver WifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
              List<ScanResult> mScanResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
              for (int i = 0; i < mScanResults.size(); i++) {
               Log.d(TAG, "get current wifi lists ->" + mScanResults.get(i).toString());   
              }
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: perhaps,my device use marshmallow.  marshmallow diffrent permission grant ?

Comment: yes you need to add permission ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,CHANGE_WIFI_STATE

Comment: if your target and compile sdk higher then lolipop then follow this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html